# Nodemon app crashed- waiting for file changes before starting

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I was trying to make a web application using MERN stack and while connecting to database using cluster and here is some error like **[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting.**

```
    import express from 'express';
    import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
    import mongoose from 'mongoose';
    import cors from 'cors';

    const app = express();

    app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
    app.use(cors());

    const CONNECTION_URL = 
    'mongodb+srv://javascriptmastery:javascriptmastery12345@cluster0.pcar8oj.mongodb.net/? 
    ]retryWrites=true&w=majority'
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

    mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then( () => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port : ${PORT}`) ))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

    mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

Comment: could you please help with logs

Comment: You need to change the connection Url ..  you are just using the connection url in the course you are following... that atlas db could be deleted..  Create a collection in atlas and connect it with your app...

Comment: As the error said, you backend had an error (there should be something in the logs ...) And until you do something to fix that error, nodemon won't restart the backend, because it probably will crash again....

Comment: Change connection Url   and then restart server 
const CONNECTION_URL = "mongodb://localhost:27017/YourDBName"

Answer (score 1):

There's a tiny mistake in your code. Your connection string may be a problem, you need to provide a database name, it should be something like:

```
'mongodb+srv://javascriptmastery:javascriptmastery12345@cluster0.pcar8oj.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
```